# How to add css style in php email?

Tags: php, html, css

How can i add tag inside the email php ? for instance , i want to bold my $for_pass .Any idea ? thanks

```
$subject = "Password Recovery";
$message = "Hi! Your member password is <strong>$for_pass</strong>";
$from = "smilepartyplanner2014@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
 // send mail
$mail_sent = @mail( $forgot_email, $subject, $message,$headers );
 //echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";

?>
<script>

alert("Your password has been sent to your email address. ");

</script>
<?php
```

Comment: so what output you get for `<strong>` ?? Is your text appearing bold or not ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need send MIME headers in your mail to tell its HTML, as follows:

```
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$mail_sent = @mail($forgot_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: You won't be using the suppress (`@`) in production though, right?

Comment: thanks you so much . I want to ask you another question is if i put background image does it must be a link or set the background url as usual ?

Comment: You can set the background url as the full path of the image:
`<div style="background: url('http://example.com/path/to/image.png');">...</div>`

Comment: able to put like this ? `<div style="background: url('images/image.png');">...</div>`

Comment: No. I don't think so. You need the absolute path to the image.

Comment: i have used images hosting to hosted my image as background u said but the output still doesn't have background image.

Comment: Try adding the image using the `<img>` tag, or the `background` attribute in HTML. The email application might be stripping out the CSS. Also, please ask a different question rather than continuing discussion in the comments. You may want to check [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=background+image+mail+php) first.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it in the mail body but you need to declare content type on header

```
  ...
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From:" . $from;
```

the message body can have any inline styling you wish.